# Improving performance of constantly repainted web page areas

Tags: html, css, performance, web, css-animations

I am currently faced with a situation, for which I need to constantly render a flickering animation within a web page. This is currently done by means of CSS, using `animation: 0.05s step-end infinite keyframe_name`. The keyframe changes the button's `background-color` at 0% and 50%. As can be expected, using Chrome's Dev tools, this area is constantly being re-painted by the browser, which is leading to an overall poor performance.

I am aware that the use of certain properties, such as the `will-change` property, or even using the `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` hack, will enable hardware accelerated rendering. However, opting for either of these options, still hasn't resulted in the desired performance improvement.

The following shows some basic code for what I am trying to achieve (optimizations are not included in code snippet):

```
@keyframes keyframe_name 
{
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  50% { background-color: blue; }
}

button 
{
  animation: 0.05s step-end infinite keyframe_name;
}
```

According to a number of online resources, it seems that only the `transform` and `opacity` CSS properties make it possible for the browser to optimize compositing. Since neither of these properties can be used to achieve my desired goals, which other approach/es could possibly lead to a performance enhancement, when it comes to the in-browser rendering of such a resource-intensive graphic?